# When creating and using the GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, rule

I am about to start my first ever company project! and ofcourse i want to do it right and use all i have learned.

Now ofcourse the UI is important for the company and also for me. My question to you guys is: Is there a common rule of thumbs when creating GUI and using elements of the gui in the logic of the program? do you devide it into as many subclasses as possible or do you create alot of different objects or do you simply have just 1 large GUI class that does everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no general answer to this question, it really depends on the project. In a rather small project it might be easier to just have one single GUI-class, but for large projects the principle "divide and conquer" is essential for the success. Otherwise you won't be able to understand your own program after a while, because there is just too much code in a single file.

My advice is to just start and divide the project as you think it would be best. After working on it for a while, you might figure out a better way. But then again refactoring in the sense of extracting/merging classes isn't that much work. And for the next project you'll be able to do it a little better from the start.

Answer (score 1):

**Divide and conquer!** You certainly don't want one big class with thousands of lines of code that mix all kind of stuff.